Download Intune custom policy based reports using Graph API
I am designing a pipeline that extracts some reports from Intune using the Graph API.
I am referring to the documentation about what all reports I can download and was able to download one from the list.
We also have some custom policy based reports in device configurations created by some of our team mates and I want to download them as well. But I am getting this error when I try to extract the custom report
'message': 'PostExportJobAsync not supported for reportType Unknown.
Is there a way to extract custom policy based reports? Or is that not supported?
Thanks in advance
